# Was this an idiomatic and prudent way to extend R's matrix multiplication syntax? Should I have used R's object system?

Tags: object-oriented, matrix, r, macros

After reading one too many Lisp books, I decided to try extending R's syntax. My goal was to implement repeated matrix multiplication in a way such that I could write `matrix%^%n` to produce the result from multiplying `matrix` by itself `n` times (where `n` is a natural number). I produced the following working code that gives the expected outputs, but found it unsatisfactory.

```
`%^%`<-function(squareMat,exponent)
{
  stopifnot(is.matrix(squareMat),is.numeric(exponent),exponent%%1==0)
  out<-diag(nrow = nrow(squareMat))
  for(i in seq_len(exponent)){out<-squareMat%*%out}
  out
}
testMatrix<-matrix(c(0,10,20,30),2,2)
lapply(0:3,function(k) testMatrix%^%k)#tests
```

For the purposes of this question, I'm happy to ignore the contents of my `for` loop. I know that it's not optimised. What I'm more interested in investigating is if this was a prudent way to extend R's syntax. I have listed my objection to my code below. If they are valid, how can they be addressed?

1. The method for checking if `exponent` is an integer is pathetic. [I don't think that doing better is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3476782/10319707), but I would dearly love to be proven wrong.
2. My strongest objection is that I believe that this problem calls for an S3 or S4 solution, but I do not believe that one is possible. `isS4(testMatrix)` tells me that matrices are not S4 objects, ruling that out. S3 might be possible, but I'm unsure if this will make problem #1 even worse (because S3 is not very strict on types) or requiring risky hacking of the `matrix` type.
3. Because of problem #1, `stopifnot` does not throw useful error messages.
4. The job of throwing errors regarding the multiplication is delegated to `%*%`. I'm OK with that, but I don't know if I should be.
5. Again, ignoring the content of the `for` loop, was `for` actually the right thing to use? Is there something like an `apply` family function for "the index of my loop doesn't actually matter, I just want to run this code `seq_len(exponent)` times"?

Comment: When I tagged this yesterday, we had an S3 tag. It's now being redirected to some Amazon stuff. I don't know why this is. Is there a better tag for R's OOP?